# Animated Flash Charts

Tags: flash, charts

I've searched but there are so many different options, so i decided to ask if do you know of any good and free animated flash charts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you looked at FusionCharts Free @ http://www.fusioncharts.com/free - it's free and open-source (MIT/GPL).